# Laravel redirect to controller action with Request object

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, redirect

In a Laravel 5.6 app I have a controller managing a product tree. The getTree() method is building up the tree from the db, the updateTree() modifies it. Both methods are called via ajax accepting Request parameters:

blade:

```
$.get("{{ URL::to('api/gettree') }}", {
  data: $("#data").val()
  }, function(response) { ... });

$.post("{{ URL::to('api/updatetree') }}", {
  data: $("#data").val()
  }, function(response) { ... });
```

routes:

```
Route::get("/gettree", "TreeController@getTree");
Route::post("/updatetree", "TreeController@updateTree");
```

controller:

```
class TreeController extends Controller
{
  public function updateTree(Request $request)
  {
    ... process $request->input() ...
    return redirect()->action("TreeController@getTree");
  }

  public function getTree(Request $request)
  {
    ...
    return view("admin.partials.itemtree", compact("data"));
  }
...
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to fire the getTree() method via a redirect to controller action after updateTree() has run, however this way I am failing to pass the Request object expected by getTree(). How would you go about this? Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check out the [signature](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html#method_action) of the `action` method, the second argument is for parameters.

So you can pass the params like so:

```
return redirect()->action("TreeController@getTree", [$request]);
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `Request $request` argument from your `getTree` method and just use something like `$request = request()`

Comment: Thanks Paras, it works well! I should have figured it out myself.

Comment: However, if you want to pass an array as parameter, you should omit the [ ] from the call, otherwise you have an error exception "Array to string conversion".

Comment: I don't think that's the case @Malvolio. Even if you want to pass an array as a first param, I think you still need to wrap it in an array because this acts as an array of parameters, with the first param as an array. You can check it out if you'd like

Comment: I have checked it like that:
   public function methodOne() {
      $param = ["key" => "value"];
      return redirect()->action("Controller@methodTwo", $param);
   }

   public function methodTwo(Request $request) { return $request->input();  }

If I put $param in brackets in the redirect, I get "Array to string conversion" error.

Comment: `methodTwo` receives $request not a string. I dont understand this example

Comment: I was too confused about that. In fact, the error exception is thrown by the return redirect, not by the receiving method.

Comment: The problem here is that all request parameters will be visible right in the URL. Is there a way to send'em hidden? Maybe redirect to a `Route::post` instead?